# AWS - Stop load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

According to [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/es/free/) I have 750h of load balancer. I would like to try create more than one load balancer.
Now I want to stop it in order to avoid waste the free plan.

But I don't find any "stop" button.
[image]

Answer (score 51):

There is no way to stop a load balancer. To avoid being billed for the time, you need to remove it.

Comment: This is dumb.  AWS is supposed to be only be charged what you need.  A load balancer and RDS instance should be able to stop it.  Sure it isn't hard to kill and create a load balancer, but I shouldn't have to.  Plus, if you have a domain name pointed at it, the new ELB will have a new dns name.

Comment: @Booyah You can now stop an RDS temporarily for about 7 days! :)

Comment: AWS is making false promises by showing "State: active" for ALBs. The only other states are "provisioning" and "failed" :-(
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#load-balancer-state

Comment: @Booyah It's extremely dumb however it's possible to create an ELB Alias in "Route 53" for the load balancer, using a Hosted Zone; this way your application's DNS would CNAME that alias. Since you will ensure the load-balancer alias name be constant across load balancer launches the CNAME will point at a newly created load balancer whenever the load balancer has been re-created and is "Active". How? For public-facing load balancers you'll designate Route 53 hosted zone a primary zone for a Subdomain (of your app's primary domain), or for a Domain (we buy a new domain with a root domain of .co)

Comment: @Booyah This is a snippet of CloudFormation for automation of LB creation: `"Resources" : {
 "WebLoadBalancer" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties" : { .. }
 },
  "ELBAlias" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
   "Properties" : {
    "AliasTarget" : {
     "DNSName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WebLoadBalancer", "DNSName" ]},
     "HostedZoneId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WebLoadBalancer", "CanonicalHostedZoneID" ]}
    },
    "HostedZoneName" : "yourdomain.co.",
    "Name": "elbWow.yourdomain.co",
    "Type": "A"
   }
  },
`